# Unable to Build React Native Expo project using EAS: Pod install exited with non-zero code: 1

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, mobile-development, eas

I have an expo react native app built and published on App & Google Stores. After a minor update, I've been trying to build and publish the new version, but I have been having a "pod install exited with non-zero code: 1" error after I run

```
eas build --platform ios
```

Below is the error I found in the error log:

```
Pod install took 93 [s] to run
[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.
undefined method `__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x0000000147d89800>
/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Podfile:66:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-core-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:196:in `post_install!'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:1013:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:1001:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:1000:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:337:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in `write!'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:336:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:315:in `create_and_save_projects'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:307:in `generate_pods_project'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:183:in `integrate'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in `install!'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/Users/expo/.gems/arm64/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
[!] Can't merge pod_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["expo-dev-menu", "Main", "ReactNativeCompatibles", "SafeAreaView", "Vendored"]. Singular build setting DEFINES_MODULE has different values.
[!] Can't merge pod_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["expo-dev-menu", "Main", "ReactNativeCompatibles", "SafeAreaView", "Vendored"]. Singular build setting DEFINES_MODULE has different values.
```

Please help.
PS: I am using Macbook and Node version 20.11.1

Thanks

I checked package.json to see if I have anything like a pod, but I don't have any. I then tried to downgrade my nodejs to see if it could work, but it also didn't.

I don't know what to do again.

Comment: Check [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42070)

Comment: what is your minor update? did you use all recommended lib as per expo required? check it using npx expo install --check

Comment: The update is related to expo push notification. I learned that is not getting the device pushToken for the notification. So, I adjusted my logic a bit and it worked. But unable build and push for production